# Build multi-architecture Docker images with Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: docker, bitbucket, buildx

From [this guide](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/run-docker-commands-in-bitbucket-pipelines/#Docker-BuildKit-restrictions) it appears that it's not possible to build multi-architecture Docker images (i.e. `docker buildx build`) using Bitbucket Pipelines:

> **Docker BuildKit restrictions**
>
> To protect the security of our users, the
> following Docker BuildKit features have been disabled in addition to
> the features listed in Running Docker commands:
>
> - multi-architecture builds
> - the --platform option (such as docker run --platform linux/arm/v7)
> - the Docker BuildKit Buildx plugin

Comment: I haven't used bitbucket pipelines, but if they say you can't, then most probably you can't. There are external tools however, which might help you - https://depot.dev/ is one such

Comment: @dsax7 depot.dev looks like it does the job, thanks.